# Is there something like a Resource Constrained Project Scheduling Problem with Discrete Cash Flows?

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

There is a lot of literature to find for the Resource Constrained Project Scheduling Problem with Discounted Cash Flow (RCPSPDC), which as the name says always use a discount function to get the Net Present Value (NPV) of each activity.

Now the problem that I am trying to solve is a little different. Instead of having a discount function that can give a NPV for an acitivity depending on the time the acitivity is executed, each "activity-to-year-assignment" has its own discrete cash flow. So different to the RCPSPDC, in which the NPV of every activity always decreases the further it gets delayed, in this problem the value of an acitivity at any time t is arbitrary (but known of course). This basically breaks every algorithm that can be found (or at least I found) for the RCPSPDC, because they all rely on the activities value being highest at the earliest start and decreasing from there. Take "A Branch and Bound Procedure for the Resource Constrained Project Scheduling Problem with Discounted Cash Flows" (Icmeli and Erenguc 1996) as an example, which employs the concept of "minimal delaying alternatives" that is based on the above mentioned assumptions.

The best approach I could think of so far is to solve the problem as a Multi-Resource Generalized Assignment Problem as in "Algorithms for the Multi-Resource Generalized Assignment Problem" (Gavish and Hasan 1991), which in turn gives rise to new questions and problems because it does not address things like precedence constraints or activity durations.

Does anyone here know any literature on the topic I'm looking for or key words I can search for? Thanks!